# How to reformat the following file info which has dynamic value?

Tags: java

I need to categorize by the department code and the department line should not be duplicated as well.

Example, DEPART160~N~ABCD~A01 ==> In this A01 is the department code which comes at the end. This A01 value will be dynamic in the file.

After processing the input file, we need to sent the output file as categorized below.

**Input**

```
COMPANY100~ABCD~SAJED~1~1~1
COMPANY150~200605049829~ ~ ~1~ ~1
DEPART160~N~ABCD~A01
EMP180~N~3~BAKK 5401281~46~D~11
DEPART160~N~ABCD~A02
EMP180~N~3~BAKK 5401282~46~D~11
DEPART160~N~ABCD~K06
EMP180~N~4~BAKK 5401283~47~D~11
DEPART160~N~ABCD~K07
EMP180~N~4~BAKK 5401284~48~D~11
DEPART160~N~ABCD~K06
EMP180~N~4~BAKK 5401285~49~D~11
DEPART160~N~ABCD~A02
EMP180~N~3~B081 5401286~49~D~11
DEPART160~N~ABCD~K07
EMP180~N~3~B082 5401287~49~D~11
```

**Expected Output**

```
COMPANY100~ABCD~SAJED~1~1~1
COMPANY150~200605049829~ ~ ~1~ ~1
DEPART160~N~ABCD~A01
EMP180~N~3~BAKK 5401281~46~D~11 
DEPART160~N~ABCD~A02
EMP180~N~3~BAKK 5401282~46~D~11
EMP180~N~3~B081 5401286~49~D~11 
DEPART160~N~ABCD~K06
EMP180~N~4~BAKK 5401283~47~D~11
EMP180~N~4~BAKK 5401285~49~D~11
DEPART160~N~ABCD~K07
EMP180~N~4~BAKK 5401284~48~D~11
EMP180~N~3~B082 5401287~49~D~11
```

Could someone help me with the code snippet or logic ?

Thanks.

Comment: Read the string line by line, if the string starts with DEPART store it as a key in hashtable with List<String> as values, if key exists add next line to its value list, else create new key and add next line.

Answer (score 0):

```
    List<String> companyValues = new ArrayList<>();
    TreeMap<String, List<String>> content = new TreeMap<>();
    StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(string, delimiter);
    String earlierLine = null;
    while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
        String line = st.nextToken().trim();
        if(line.contains("COMPANY100") || line.contains("COMPANY150")) {
            // addCompany
            companyValues.add(line);
        } else if(line.startsWith("DEPART160")) {
            earlierLine = line;
        } else {
            if (!content.containsKey(earlierLine)) {
                content.put(earlierLine, new ArrayList<String>());
            }
            content.get(earlierLine).add(line);
        }
    }

    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    for(String companyValue: companyValues) {
        sb.append(companyValue);
        sb.append(delimiter);
    }
    for(Map.Entry<String, List<String>> entry : content.entrySet()) {
        String key = entry.getKey();
        List<String> values = entry.getValue();
        sb.append(key);
        sb.append(delimiter);
        for(String value: values) {
            sb.append(value);
            sb.append(delimiter);
        }
    }
    sb.toString()
```